# Port Forward based on condition in Twisted

Tags: networking, twisted

I am trying to write a port-forwarder in Twisted, that will forward to port 8000 if an IP address is already in the cache & to another port - say 4000 if not. I already have the cache written, but am having issues with where to add logic to the portforwarding with Twisted.

Take this simple example:

```
class LoggingProxyServer(portforward.ProxyServer):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        portforward.ProxyServer.dataReceived(self, data)

class LoggingProxyFactory(portforward.ProxyFactory):
    protocol = LoggingProxyServer
```

What twisted method do I override to add the cache checking?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone sorry, I edited the question. A user is simply the ip address from the get request, at least initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ProxyServer.connectionMade` is responsible for setting up the TCP connection that is outgoing from the proxy process.  It uses the `host` and `port` attributes of its factory to decide what it's going to use as the destination of that connection attempt.

If you want to vary the behavior of the proxy, that's the code you'll need to override.

You can easily find the IP address of the client which has connected to `ProxyServer`.  The `ProxyServer` instance has a `transport` attribute that refers to an `ITransport` provider (probably an `ITCPTransport` provider if your proxy is listening for incoming TCP connections).

Transports have methods to tell you the addresses of their two endpoints.  `getHost` tells you the local address and `getPeer` tells you the remote address.

So, for example, you could write a conditional that had one behavior for all TCP clients with IP addresses starting with a `1` and something else for all TCP clients with other IP addresses:

```
if self.transport.getPeer().host.startswith("1"):
    ...
else:
    ...
```